Using Double Sanitary Tee arms for sink drain and toilet vent
I am having to re-plumb my bathroom, and am trying to follow IPC 2018 as best I can (I live in Vermont).
The current Stack Vent, which exits the roof, is 3" copper and currently only vents the toilet. As I am now replacing the toilet, and remodeling the bathroom, I figured it was a good time to open the wall and tee off the stack so the other fixtures can be vented. This is a single story home with a basement.
The part I am having difficulty with is where the sink drain is entering one side of the Double Sanitary Tee, and the toilet vent on the other side. Is this a correct way of venting? If so, what vent type would this be considered? I thought it resembled a "Common Vent", but I am not sure if the toilet vent side is considered wet when the sink drain is at the same level...

The design is rough, where the pipe lengths are for illustration purposes only. But the fittings should be according to the IPC (I hope). Here is a link to the design: https://make.craftyamigo.com/design/XhYmlsfUlTO7OuIhAAuxL5gISfq1/boyC6AeRJbU9ap56pBVb

From another angle:

Update:
A suggestion on another forum was to do away with the tee, and let the water closet wet vent through the sink plumbing. This is probably the better way to go, but I am still curious to know if the original design is a valid way of venting.

Nicely detailed.

To answer your question "Is this a correct way of venting?":
In this situation, I would wet vent the toilet through the sink. This would require the pipe from the tee at the sink to the tee at the toilet to be 2" not 1-1/2". That would be the correct way for most plumbers.
Is there anything wrong with the way that you have shown it?
There are four things that I see:

The vent for the toilet is flat before the flood level rim of the toilet. This would be an issue with my local code, and I think also with IPC 2018:


905.3 Vent connection to drainage system. Every dry vent connecting to a horizontal drain shall connect above the centerline of
the horizontal drain pipe.
905.4 Vertical rise of vent. Every dry vent shall rise vertically to a point not less than 6 inches (152 mm) above the flood level rim
of the highest trap or trapped fixture being vented.

As the dry vent is connecting to a vertical drain pipe and not a horizontal pipe, so it should pass the requirement of 905.3. However, it does run horizontally below 6 inches above the flood level rim of the toilet so I would say that it fails the requirement of 905.4.
This could be fixed by installing a fitting 45 elbow into the tee and rising at 45° up and then using a second 45 elbow to transition to vertical keeping it nominally vertical.

The vent for the bathtub runs horizontally below the flood level rim of the bathtub. This too would fail the requirement of 905.4.

Running the pipe vertically to 6 inches above the bathtub's flood level rim will conflict with the tub spout. So once again, you can offset the vent with two 45 elbows so that you can run it vertically to the side of the tub spout.

The transition from vertical to horizontal at both the sink and the bathtub would fail my local code as we require the use of two 45° elbows. I'm not familiar with the IPC but my quick look didn't find this requirement. I'm sure that you would require at the minimum the use of a long sweep 90° elbow for the vertical to horizontal change in direction.

The drain for the bathtub has a 90° elbow for change of direction. This would fail my local code but once again I'm not familiar with IPC to know if this is okay with that code. I would suspect that at minimum it would have to be a long sweep 90° elbow if not two 45° elbows.




Thank you for the very thorough explanation with references. I do see in 2018 IPC 706.3 that a short sweep or quarter bend for 2" or smaller only. It probably would not hurt to go with a long sweep as there is room for one.
